# How does "scatterlist" works in linux?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, dma

As we know scatter list gathers the memory scattered physically across the memory, but virtually contiguous though. When communicating with DMA it provides an abstracted view of memory to DMA as of this is memory contiguous physically.

How does `scatterlist` handle this? Is it a kind of linked list maintained within the `scatterlist`?

For example if have 4000 bytes of data to be transferred using DMA ,as data is physically contiguous how scatter list makes it contiguous ? will scatterlist implementation allocate 4000 bytes of data using `Kmalloc` to make sure that it gets a physically contiguous memory? or will it
create a linked list?

Note: here my query is not about the SG table,but about an individual scatterlist

Let us say we want to hold the data of 4000 bytes of physically discontiguous memory

```
struct scatterlist sg,
sg_init_one(&sg,data,4000)
```

Now how does this sg addresses the issue?

Comment: In your example, how is `data` allocated? :)

Comment: data can come from user space or from other kernel interfaces ,but it is guaranteed that data comes a scatter-list . regarding allocation we do not have any control it could be from malloc(user space) or kmalloc(kernel space) etc.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you are mixing two different scatter lists, i.e. `struct scatterlist` in Linux kernel and scatter list that might be supported by the specific DMA controller. In both cases they are not contiguous. This is like an array in the first case and linked list in the second. When you call `dmaengine_prep_slave_sg()` the actual DMA controller driver converts it to the internal structure which might be the copy of the SG list, a new SG list that fits in the maximum DMA block size boundaries, the DMA HW linked list and so on. Depending on the DMA controller driver (let's consider recently added *drivers/dma/hsu/hsu.c*) the initial SG list is copied and supplied to the hardware in chunks by at most 4 DMA HW descriptors, after finish of each block it gets an interrupt and continues if the initial amount of items is more than 4 until everything is sent / received.

### Example

Let's assume we have the following in the SG list that is supplied to DMA controller on the system where the maximum size of DMA block is **1024** (this is usually set by `dma_set_max_seg_size()` for callers to know about it) and memory page size is **4096** (to be sure that we have contiguous data when the size is less than a page):

|  | Virtual address | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0xa000 | 0x555 |
| 2 | 0x7000 | 0x111 |

This, due to DMA controller constraints, become

|  | Virtual address | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0xa000 | 0x400 |
| 2 | 0xa400 | 0x155 |
| 3 | 0x7000 | 0x111 |

either on the caller (user of DMA controller) or callee (DMA controller itself). On top of that for the blocks 2 and 3 DMA controller driver may apply additional alignment rules, such as **4-byte** boundary for each burst. With that it becomes

|  | Virtual address | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0xa000 | 0x400 |
| 2 | 0xa400 | 0x154 |
| 3 | 0xa450 | 0x001 |
| 4 | 0x7000 | 0x110 |
| 5 | 0x7110 | 0x001 |

and DMA controller will service the **5** separate data blocks.

Comment: in case if I need to  "get the list of the physical addresses" (non-contiguous in RAM) from scatter list ,how can I do it? because I need to retrieve this physical address of buffers.is it something below:                               EX:
int i, count = pci_map_sg(dev, sglist, nents, direction); 
struct scatterlist *sg;

for (i = 0, sg = sglist; i < count; i++, sg++) { 
hw_address[i] = sg_dma_address(sg); 
hw_len[i] = sg_dma_len(sg); 
}

where nents is the number of entries in the sglist.

reference: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/Documentation/DMA-API.txt#L332

Comment: I have no idea why do you need *physical* addresses here, but in the `scatterlist` you have *virtual* address accompanying *bus* address. Bus address is what you get by `sg_dma_address(sg)` and it's quaranteed to be in DMA capable memory.